# Telegram client updates and API requests over same session

Tags: c#, multithreading, api, sockets, telegram

I'm coding a custom C# telegram client starting from TLSharp and modified it in order to support layer 54.

I want handle both receiving updates from telegram servers and using the API without opening a separate session to do this.

The problem is basically a multithreaded access to the socket connected to the Telegram Server.

Here it is the scheme:

TelegramClient <------- socket_1[(session_1)] --------> TelegramServer

The problem is that in order to receive constantly updates from telegram server I use a while(true) cycle that 
basically is schematized as:

```
while(true){
    data_cipher = await socket_1.receive() // listen for new stuff from the socket_1
    data_plain  = decrypt(data_cipher)  // decrypt 
    processUpdate(data_plain)  // process the update
}
```

Now if I want ,for example, query telegram servers for the list of all the chats in which am I registered, I have 
to access the socket_1 in order to send this request, and wait for the answer, but socket_1 is in listening and I obviously can't access it.

One solution could be to use a vector of request that will be processed after an update has been received,
the idea is something like this:

```
List<Request> pending_requests = new List<Request>() // list of requests added by another thread 

    while(true){

        data_cipher = await socket_1.receive() // listen for new stuff from the socket_1
        data_plain  = decrypt(data_cipher)  // decrypt 
            processUpdate(data_plain)  // process the update

        if(pending_requests.Count != 0){
            foreach(Request r in pending_requests ){
                     processRequest(r)
                }
            }
    }
```

This solution is quite horrible, since we process a request only after an update, and so no update = no request processed...

Another possibility could be to use some kind of lock mechanism following a scheme like this:

```
//Thread_updater
//--------------------------------------------
while(true){

        lock(socket_1){
    data_cipher = await socket_1.receive() // listen for new stuff from the socket_1
    }

    data_plain  = decrypt(data_cipher)  // decrypt 
        handleUpdate(data_plain)  // process the update

}
--------------------------------------------


//Thread_requests
//--------------------------------------------
Request r = new Request(<stuff>);

lock(socket_1){
   await sendRequest(r,socket_1)
}

--------------------------------------------
```

The big problem about this is that once the Thread_updater takes the lock, it will never release it until an update has been received... this is basically the same problem as before.
I've tried also to play with CancellationTasks or Socket Timeout, but I felt like I'm taking a wrong path.

Is there an elegant solution/pattern in order to handle this in a neat way? 
As said , I don't want to open 2 sessions since it is logically wrong ( it would be like having two clients in order to handle receiving of updates and sending messages ).

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler way to do this.

This is what I have done in VB.net, but should also work for you in C#.

- Setup your socket and connect to Telegram Servers, listening for data
- Buffer data as it is received
- process received data - decode TL types received from Telegram and either store/ react i.e send messages in response to what you have received
- while listening, you can also send messages through the same socket

**Sample Code**

## Region "Variables"

```
    Const BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 64

    Private soc As Socket
    Private ep As EndPoint
    Private connected As Boolean
    Private efSent As Boolean
    Private are As New AutoResetEvent(False)
#End Region

#Region "Network"
    Public Sub Connect(Optional ip As String = "149.154.167.40", Optional port As Integer = 443)
        soc = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) With {.SendBufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE, .SendTimeout = 3000}

        Try
            ep = GetIPEndPointFromHostName(ip, port)

            Dim arg = New SocketAsyncEventArgs With {.RemoteEndPoint = ep, .UserToken = "Connect_ARGS"}
            AddHandler arg.Completed, AddressOf IO_Handler

            While Not connected
                Try
                    If Not soc.ConnectAsync(arg) Then
                        IO_Handler(soc, arg)
                    End If

                    are.WaitOne(4000)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Thread.Sleep(1000)
                End Try
            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            Log("Connect: " & ex.ToString, ConsoleColor.Red, True)
        End Try

        ReadData()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Disconnect()
        connected = False
        loggedin = False

        soc.Disconnect(False)
        soc = Nothing

        Log("Disconnect", ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, True, True, True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Send(m As PlainMessage)
        SendData(m.data, True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Send(m As EncryptedMessage)
        SendData(m.data, True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendData(b() As Byte, Optional read As Boolean = False)
        b = TCPPack(b)

        Dim arg = New SocketAsyncEventArgs With {.RemoteEndPoint = ep, .UserToken = "Send_ARGS"}
        AddHandler arg.Completed, AddressOf IO_Handler
        arg.SetBuffer(b, 0, b.Length)

        Try
            If Not soc.SendAsync(arg) Then
                IO_Handler(soc, arg)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log("SendData: " & ex.ToString, ConsoleColor.Red)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub IO_Handler(sender As Object, e As SocketAsyncEventArgs)
        Select Case e.SocketError
            Case SocketError.Success
                Select Case e.LastOperation
                    Case SocketAsyncOperation.Connect 'A socket Connect operation.
                        connected = True
                        Log("Connected to " & e.ConnectSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString, ConsoleColor.Green)
                        are.Set()
                    Case SocketAsyncOperation.Disconnect
                        connected = False
                        RaiseEvent Disconneted()
                    Case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive 'A socket Receive operation.
                        If e.BytesTransferred = 0 Then 'no pending data
                            Log("The remote end has closed the connection.")
                            If connected Then
                                ReadData()
                            End If

                            connected = False
                            loggedin = False

                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                        HandleData(e)
                End Select
            Case SocketError.ConnectionAborted
                RaiseEvent Disconneted()
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Function GetIPEndPointFromHostName(hostName As String, port As Integer) As IPEndPoint
        Dim addresses = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName)
        If addresses.Length = 0 Then
            Log("Unable to retrieve address from specified host name:  " & hostName, ConsoleColor.Red)
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Return New IPEndPoint(addresses(0), port)
    End Function

    Private Function TCPPack(b As Byte()) As Byte()
        Dim a = New List(Of Byte)
        Dim len = CByte(b.Length / 4)

        If efSent = False Then 'TCP abridged version
            efSent = True
            a.Add(&HEF)
        End If

        If len >= &H7F Then
            a.Add(&H7F)
            a.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(len)) '
        Else
            a.Add(len)
        End If

        a.AddRange(b) 'data, no sequence number, no CRC32

        Return a.ToArray
    End Function

    Private Sub ReadData()
        Dim arg = New SocketAsyncEventArgs With {.RemoteEndPoint = ep, .UserToken = "Read_ARGS"}
        AddHandler arg.Completed, AddressOf IO_Handler

        Dim b(BUFFER_SIZE - 1) As Byte
        arg.SetBuffer(b, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)

        Try
            If Not soc.ReceiveAsync(arg) Then
                IO_Handler(soc, arg)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log("ReadMessages: " & ex.ToString, ConsoleColor.Red)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleData(e As SocketAsyncEventArgs)
        Log("<< " & B2H(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesTransferred), ConsoleColor.DarkGray, True, logTime:=False)
        Try
            Dim len As Integer = e.Buffer(0)
            Dim start = 1

            If len = &H7F Then
                len = e.Buffer(1)
                len += e.Buffer(2) << 8
                len += e.Buffer(3) << 16
                start = 4
            End If

            len = 4 * len

            Dim d(len - 1) As Byte
            Array.Copy(e.Buffer, start, d, 0, len)

            ProcessResponse(d)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        ReadData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessResponse(data As Byte())
        'process the data received - identify the TL types returned from Telegram, then store / handle each as required
    End Sub
#End Region
```